# Find delimiter and ignore delimiter inside quotes

Tags: java, regex

I have the following regex pattern:`(?iu)[(?=\s)]\bgo\b(?!\S)`

It's working to split by delimiter `go`, basically it catches the whole world and ignores special characters like `#go` or `--go` so it doesn't considered these delimiters.

What I need now its to ignore the delimiters inside comments, like: `select 'something go something' from table1 go --`

It should only find one delimiter and return `select 'something go something' from table 1` and `--`. Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

--
...update question above:

@randomducks, thanks for the tip, as far has I could test the solution works fine.

Right now i have the following pattern:

`(?=(([^']+'){2})*[^']*$)(?iu)[(?=\s)]\bgo\b(?!\S)|^go|go$`

`(?=(([^']+'){2})*[^']*$)` : Ignore delimiter inside quoted text

`(?iu)[(?=\s)]\bgo\b(?!\S)` : catch delimiter "go"

`|^go|go$` : also catch beginning and end of string/line delimiter.

Know all i need is to ignore delimiter inside comments, like /* go */. I tried adapting the pattern above to do this but, no luck so far.

Comment: what is the purpose of this? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Filter T-SQL code. And I already am doing it. But I still have a problem with delimiters inside quotes. I want to ignore them. PS: The pattern can be tested with split() method from String.

Comment: I feel like regex is not a good option for ignoring text in quotes.
If you aren't restricted to using a regex, the answer to this question is worth looking into. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917932/regex-to-ignore-text-between-quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're stuck splitting the string using a regex, one possible solution might be to use the regex to check for an even number of quotes as mentioned by @anubhava here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10864960/2788862

For your question, the solution would be

```
(?=(([^']+'){2})*[^']*$)(?iu)[(?=\s)]\bgo\b(?!\S)
```

[You can see a working example of this here](http://ideone.com/1IwD7J)

Update:

If they're not needed, you might want to consider removing the multi-line comments and then using the regex to separate out the SQL statements. Check here for more info: http://ostermiller.org/findcomment.html

If you really want the multi-line comments included though, a regex might not be the best solution. Maybe parsing the string manually would better suite your needs. Although I've never used it, I suspect something like [antlr3](http://www.antlr3.org/) could work.

Comment: @HAT, I'm looking into how you can ignore delimiters inside comments. In the meantime, the moderators will probably want any further questions either added on as comments or as edits in the original question, so can you please move your second question to the end of your original question? Thanks :-)

Comment: @HAT, do the comments inside /* and */ need to be included or would it be okay if they were removed?

Comment: I would prefer that the comments stay, just that the delimiter would be ignored, but removing the comments is better than considering the delimiter inside them, which is what I have now.

Comment: thanks for the tip, I wanted to do all in a single pattern, but I'm not having much luck with that, I had already visited the link you provided but it was the opposite of what I needed. In lack of an all in one solution, removing the comments and then using the pattern I already have seems to be a good workaround. thanks again.