# Notepad++ ignoring end delimiter of RegEx

Tags: regex, notepad++, pcre

I have a JSON file. There is some information I want to delete and the process would be quite tedious to be done manually, and incredibly quick to perform through RegEx.

I want to find matches starting by, let's say, "abc" (including quotes), composed by any set of characters (including conflicting ones like brackets), and ending by , (the comma character), new line and " (left quote character).

Although RegEx is not my best strength, I have read several questions that could be related, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20380968/find-delimiter-and-ignore-delimiter-inside-quotes), and tried out several patterns, being this the one in which I believe the most:

```
"abc"(.*),^"
```

But it doesn't work properly. It starts fine, but the part after the (.*) is completely ignored, so the rest of the text in the document is selected instead of only what I requested.

Comment: The patterns provided by Tim and HamZa below seem to work for me in Notepad++ v6.5.2 on Windows. What does your JSON file look like? Does it perhaps have whitespace at the beginning of lines?

Comment: Yeah, just tried a minimized example since the file is quite huge and it's working, so I guess I shall take a look at wth is wrong with the original file...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^` doesn't mean newline. It's a "zero-length [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)" that matches the position before the first character of a line.

You want something like

```
"abc"(.*),\r?\n"
```

Comment: Good to know, thanks, but the behaviour is still the same (the selection goes to the end of the document anyway.

Comment: @JorgeAntonioDíaz-Benito What about `"abc"(.*?),\r?\n"` ?

Comment: Usually, the dot doesn't match newline characters. That behavior can be changed, though (for example through an option in the search/replace dialog of many editors (but I don't know Notepad++'s options) or with a `(?s)` modifier within the regex itself.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Take a [look](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xA1Hi.png), there is indeed an option `. matches newlines` and setting an inline modifier `(?s)` is also possible

Comment: @TimPietzcker I was already using the option, thanks. But no, the new suggestion makes no change >.<

Comment: @JorgeAntonioDíaz-Benito: You were already *using* that option? No, you have to turn it *off*, of course.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Turned off no matches are shown at all.

Comment: @TimPietzcker My bad. I made it work in a tinier file. I'll look into what my concrete problem is on the original file on my own, thanks.